# Excel VBA AdvancedFilter should copy only certain columns

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to copy only certain columns from a filtered table, not all the columns?

Base code:

```
Sub GENERATE_click()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A12:E500").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("D1:F3"), _
        CopyToRange:=Range("L14"), _
        Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: You can change the `Range("A12:E500")` reference or you could copy all and then delete unwanted columns.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, you can, and your code will work. You just have to examine your criteria very well and you don't have to leave a criteria row empty. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Better way to copy all the columns and then delete programmatically unnecessary columns as SJR suggested,

Comment: @Harun24HR Why "better"? I used several advanced filters (in named ranges) to allow different users of my workbook to check and adapt several filter conditions, which are invoked by a set of buttons. Advantage: Each user can see the conditions without having to look into VBA code.

Comment: @Asger Does your code copy selected columns like advance filter is applied to Column `A:E` but copy column `A` Column `C` and Column `E`? If it then please post the code as answer so that we can learn.

Comment: But if one of the criteria cols is A but I don't wont to copy this column, is it possible to  use advancedfilter then?

Comment: @Harun24HR You are right, my answer doesn't work for "only certain columns". I thought erroneously in rows, not columns. I will delete my answer.

Comment: @Kevin As AdvancedFilter filters and copies the specified range completely, all columns will be included. I changed to separate filter + copy + unfilter actions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this (copying only columns B, C and E for example):

```
Private Sub MyAdvancedFilters()
    Dim lastVisibleRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A12:E500").AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
            CriteriaRange:=Range("D1:F3"), _
            Unique:=False
        lastVisibleRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B12:C" & lastVisibleRow & ",E12:E" & lastVisibleRow).Copy .Range("L14")
        .ShowAllData
    End With
End Sub
```